# Divisibility by 9 with negative number

Tags: divisibility

I know the rule to check divisibility by 9: check if the sum of the digits of the number is divisible by 9. But what if the number is negative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the same. Multiplying by $-1$ doesn't change whether a number is divisible by $9$.

Comment: Cool! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by -1 doesn't change anything. If we have 18, which we know is divisible by 9, we just multiply it by -1 to get -18 and then we do the same to how many times 9 goes into 18 to get -2, and see that 9 goes into -18 -2 times, -2 is an integer so the rule holds up.

Comment: actually, multiplying by -1 doesn't change anything in any divisibility test, right? if I only wanna know if a number is divisible by another... the sign would matter if I wanted to know the exact remainder, right? like -10 mod 7, which is 4 (different from 10 mod 7, which is 3)

Comment: Correct, it does not change anything in any divisibility test, but it does when dealing with modulo.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1693330 stated, the divisibility rule does not change.
You can also look at it like this:

The divisibility rule is "check if the sum of the digits of the number is divisible by 9", but "-" isn't a digit.

It is the same as other divisibilities.

Comment: Please do not repeat other answers.